# Why do I get a syntax error with no invalid tokens?

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my query:

```
"UPDATE tbl_pedidos_produtos SET status = CASE
        WHEN id IN (SELECT produto_id FROM tbl_pedidos_cotacaos_produtos) THEN 4
        ELSE 3 END WHERE pedido_id = ".$pedidosExpirados[$i]["pedido_id"]
```

And then:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong. It makes no sense.

Comment: Try putting `END CASE` instead of just `END`.

Comment: That actually gave me another error: `for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHERE pedido_id = 1' at line 3`

Comment: Yeah, sorry. That's for stored programs.

Comment: how about you post the SQL query that is generated, based on the comment you gave @Shailesh, it sounds like pedidio_id is an empty string/undefined.

Answer (score -2):

```
"UPDATE tbl_pedidos_produtos SET status = CASE
    WHEN id IN (SELECT produto_id FROM tbl_pedidos_cotacaos_produtos) THEN 4
    ELSE 3 END WHERE pedido_id = '".$pedidosExpirados[$i]["pedido_id"]."' ";
```

Comment: This removes the error, but it's a number, not a string.

Comment: Please do not pose code without support text.  Be explicit about what you've changed.  State why that would fix the OP's problem.  Help others to understand.

Answer (score -3):

```
    $query = 'UPDATE tbl_pedidos_produtos SET status = CASE
    WHEN id IN (SELECT produto_id FROM tbl_pedidos_cotacaos_produtos) THEN 4
    ELSE 3 END WHERE pedido_id = '.$pedidosExpirados[$i]["pedido_id"];
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: It makes no difference.

Comment: Sometime it doesn't get index of an array because of not using proper quotes.